# Odoo 10 Database restore error

Tags: database, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to restore database in Odoo10.

I get following error:

> "Database restore error: Command `psql` not found."

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: @odedra , Can you help me out with this?

Comment: seems you haven't installed `postgresql` or for some weird reason `psql` isn't in the system `PATH`. What's the output of `which psql` (or if you have `locate` installed `locate psql`)?

Answer (score 7):

If Odoo is already working in your system, that means you already have PGSql installed in your system.

Go to the PG Sql installation folder and find the path where you can find the `psql.exe` file. It should be in either of these locations.

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\PostgreSQL\bin'
```

OR

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\10\bin'
```

Copy the location path and go to the Odoo config file where you paste the location against the entry `pg_path` then save.

[image]

Restart the odoo service then restore the database, you should not get the error any more.

Also see this [youtube video](https://youtu.be/YCA4eVvMYUM).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Agree with @danidee comment. It seems System don't have *postgresql*

Try with following command to install in your Linux system.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql -y
```

Afterwards switch to *postgresql* user with following command.

```
sudo su postgres
```

And then follow below commands (will create Superuser name with odoo in postgres database).

```
psql
createuser -s odoo
\q
```

Now reboot your system. Try it again.

Comment: Thank you  for the inputs, I had the postgresql installed. I tried reinstalling it. Now it just says "database restore error". There is no info in the log file either. It is also added to SYSTEM path.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu

Try to find the path of PostgreSQL first using below command.

find / -name postgresql

then set the pg_path parameter in odoo config file like as below.

pg_path = /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin

Answer (score 0):

First try login as administrator

Username: **admin**

Password: **admin** or **(enter your admin password)**

and then try restoring the same database. It worked for me.